# Keep getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I am starting to become insane.

I keep getting a silly `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and I can't figure out how to fix it. I have the following code:

```
private void Send(List<SimpleRequest.LoanRequest> list)
{
    int delay = int.Parse(numericDelay.Value.ToString());

    for (int threadnumber = 0; threadnumber < list.Count; threadnumber++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RequestLoanQuote(threadnumber, list[threadnumber]));
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
}

private void RequestLoanQuote(object state, SimpleRequest.LoanRequest loanRequest)
{
    try
    {
        if (console.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AppendText("Sending: " + loanRequest.SSN + "\n");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var threadnumber = (int)state;
        using (var client = new LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient())
        {
            Utility_Tool.LoanBrokerWS.LoanQuote response = client.GetLoanQuote(loanRequest.SSN, loanRequest.LoanAmount, loanRequest.LoanDuration);
            sb.Append(response.SSNk__BackingField + " returned: ");
            sb.Append(response.interestRatek__BackingField + " | ");
            sb.Append(response.BankNamek__BackingField + "\n");
            AppendText(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--- ");
        sb.Append(loanRequest.SSN);
        sb.Append(" ---\n" + e.Message + "\n--- ");
        sb.Append(loanRequest.SSN);
        sb.Append(" END ---\n");
        AppendText(sb.ToString());
    }
}

private void AppendText(String msg)
{
    Action append = () => console.AppendText(msg);
    if (this.console.InvokeRequired)
    {
        console.BeginInvoke(append);
    }
    else
    {
        append();
    }
}
```

The below method is part of the webservice that `RequestLoanQuote()` calls:

```
public LoanQuote GetLoanQuote(string ssn, double amount, DateTime loanDuration)
{

    LoanRequest loanrequest = new LoanRequest
    {
        SSN = ssn,
        LoanAmount = amount,
        LoanDuration = loanDuration
    };

   ssn= ssn.Replace("-", "");

    Message loanMessage = new Message();
    loanMessage.Body = loanrequest;


    requestQueue.Send(loanMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("sent message for " +ssn);
    CollectionKeeper.sentmessages++;
    //finding the right response 
    LoanQuote rightquote = null;

    while (rightquote == null)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine( ssn+" is waiting for response");
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        var t = CollectionKeeper.quotes.TryRemove(ssn, out rightquote);



    }
    Console.WriteLine(ssn + " found response");
    Console.WriteLine(CollectionKeeper.sentmessages);
    return rightquote;

}
```

Comment: How large is `list`?  If `list.Count<threadnumber`, think about what happens when you call `list[threadnumber]`.

Comment: quantity makes a list with the desired size. So if quantity is 5 the `list.Count` will return 5. But what I don't understand, is why the for loop seems to be ignoring the `threadnumber < quantity` condition.

Comment: I'd nearly be willing to bet that `quantity != list.Count` when the `else` branch is taken.  Can you place a breakpoint on the `for` loop in the `else` branch and probe the values for `quantity` and `list.Count`?

Comment: `quantity` is user-entered (or appears to be, at least), but `list` is coming from somewhere else. You're never checking those against each other.

Comment: Also, you say "`threadnumber` gets to the same value as `quantity`," but it never should. At most, `threadnumber` should be `quantity - 1`.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen `Also, you say "threadnumber gets to the same value as quantity," but it never should. At most, threadnumber should be quantity - 1` yes and that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Okay, if I run the program with debugging, going step by step, it works. If I let it run without a breakpoint, the exception occurs... ._.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Key to this is delay apparently. If I add a 10 ms delay, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code either to

```
    for (int threadnumber = 0; threadnumber < list.Count; threadnumber++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RequestLoanQuote(threadnumber, list[threadnumber]));
        if (delay > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
    }
```

or do something like this

```
    int actualLimit = quantity > list.Count ? list.Count : quantity;
    for (int threadnumber = 0; threadnumber < actualLimit; threadnumber++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RequestLoanQuote(threadnumber, list[threadnumber]));
        if (delay > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
    }
```

The problem is because you're going outside the current content of the list if you use the `quantity` variable.

Lets say you had `quantity=10` but your list only has `list.Count=5`, you'd be getting the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when you access the index.

Comment: It's not really a fix, but at least I don't get that error any more. It means I have to make +1 quantity more than I want to every time, but I don't care any more xD

Comment: @Vipar, the problem here is that the Count property starts at 1, the index of the array is at 0 so eventually when you catch up with the Count property, lets say 10, your array is only at 9 since it started at 0 index. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand why. But it should never get to that value because of the for loops condition.